# How can i dynamically load CommonJs module?

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonjs

I'am working on app with `React`, `TS` and `Webpack` stack.

I need to implement feature that allows my app work with client plugins - `js` files that override existing functionality of some classes. It can be loaded from anywhere - local file system or remote repository and should be fetched in the `runtime`, because i need to have an option to specify new extension in config and just press `F5`.

Dynamic import is not my case, because as far as i understand `Webpack` needs to be able to at least guess roughly what an `import()` is meant to be referencing. Using simple 'get' request might be an option, but how can i use loaded script as `CommonJS` module in this case? And am i correct about dynamic import behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@paciolan/remote-module-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paciolan/remote-module-loader) to remotely load a common js module.

```js
import { createLoadRemoteModule } from "@paciolan/remote-module-loader"

const main = async() => {
  const loadRemoteModule = createLoadRemoteModule()
  const myModule = await loadRemoteModule("http://fake.url/modules/my-module.js")

  const value = myModule.default()
  console.log({ value })
}

main()
```

If you need to pass dependencies to the module:

```js
import {
  createLoadRemoteModule,
  createRequires
} from "@paciolan/remote-module-loader"

const dependencies = {
  react: require("react")
}

const main = async() => {
  const requires = createRequires(dependencies)
  const loadRemoteModule = createLoadRemoteModule({ requires })
  const myModule = await loadRemoteModule("http://fake.url/modules/my-module.js")

  const value = myModule.default()
  console.log({ value })
}

main()
```

If need to load a React Component, check out [@paciolan/remote-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paciolan/remote-component)

You may have to take extra steps if you have a [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) set.